# Are there any Ubuntu-based distros with LXDE in 2023?

Tags: lxde

I know about LXLE, based on Focal, and I know Lubuntu stopped using LXDE as its standard desktop a few years ago. I also recognize one can install LXDE to use with any Ubuntu-based distribution. I’m curious whether there are any other distros whose standard install uses LXDE (like Lubuntu used to do).

Comment: @noisefloor Ah, I didn’t know that (obviously!). I will wait a little to see any other responses, but I’m guessing if you make your comment a response I will be able to accept it as answering my Q.

Comment: I consider this question to be on topic despite the general wording of it to the contrary because the accepted answer shows that this question is on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dedicated thread for this topic in the forum related to the LXDE project: https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=41494.

As you correctly say, Lubuntu switched to LXQt so there is not more *buntu which comes with LXDE as the standard desktop. However, if you have a desktop-less Ubuntu installation you can add the LXDE desktop installing the lxde package: `sudo apt install lxde`. Or you use `tasksel` and select the "lxde task".

Comment: I did this a while back on a 22.04 install for a computer I maintain for an elderly relative (they were used to using Lubuntu 18.04). It works well.